Typeorm Optimize Query - Fetch Message Rooms with only the latest message
I have a MessageRoom Table that can contain many messages.
I want to fetch all rooms with only the latest message.
This is for a chat app.
     const rooms = this.roomRepository
        .createQueryBuilder("r")
        .leftJoin("r.members", "m")
        .leftJoin("m.profile", "p")
        .where("p.id = :id", {
          id: profilesId,
        })
        .leftJoinAndSelect("r.messages", "msg")
        .leftJoin(
          "r.messages",
          "next_msg",
          "msg.createdAt < next_msg.createdAt",
        )
        .andWhere("next_msg.id IS NULL")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("msg.text", "text")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("msg.authorProfile", "authorProfile")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("r.members", "members")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("members.profile", "profile")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("profile.avatar", "avatar")
        .leftJoinAndSelect("profile.title", "title")
        .orderBy("msg.createdAt", "DESC")
        .limit(20)
        .getMany();


It appears that this query is taking so much time.
How can I optimize it?
Thanks.

I removed the  language tag. Instead you can add a tag for the dbms you're using.

No worries, I use Mysql
